# Dynamic partition cannot be the parent of a static partition '3'

Tags: hive, hiveql, partition, hive-partitions

While inserting data into table hive threw the error "Dynamic partition cannot be the parent of a static partition '3'" using below query

> INSERT INTO TABLE student_partition PARTITION(course , year = 3)
>   SELECT name, id, course FROM student1 WHERE year = 3;

Please explain the reason..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason of this Exception is because partitions are hierarchical folders. `course` folder is upper level and `year` is nested folders for each year.

When you creating partitions dynamically, upper folder should be created first (course) then nested `year=3` folder.

You are providing `year=3` partition in advance (statically), even before `course` is known.

Vice-versa is possible: Static parent partition and dynamic child partition:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE student_partition PARTITION(course='chemistry' , year)  --static course partition
SELECT name, id, 3 as year --or just simply year 
  FROM student1 WHERE year = 3;
```

In the HDFS partitions folders are like this:

```
/student_table/course=chemistry/year=3
/student_table/course=chemistry/year=4
/student_table/course=philosophy/year=3
```

Static partition should exist. But it cannot exist if parent is not defined yet.

Alternatively you can make `year` partition dynamic as well:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE student_partition PARTITION(course , year) 
SELECT name, id, course, 3 as year --or just simply year 
  FROM student1 WHERE year = 3;
```